# Virtual Credit/Coins in mobile application

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

Does there any existing good API for virtual Coins purchase in mobile application? Actually, I would like to make a cross platform application. I have researched on facebook, there is a facebook API for purchase. But it only for facebook application/games.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, each app store/market wants you to use them to handle payments, so that they can take a cut (usually 30%) of your profits. Using third party payment providers is generally forbidden by the terms of use, etc. Thus, it is unlikely that you will find a cross-platform solution. PayPal should work on most platforms, but you have to make sure it's not against the  terms of use. For Android, you can use unmanaged items with in-app billing, there should be something similar for the iPhone. You could probably manage your coins on your own server, and have them purchased on each platform with the required payment provider, but it's quite a lot of work.

Comment: Android provide in-app billing?

Comment: For more than an year now. Do some creative Googling :)

Comment: I really think Paypal is NOT authorized on Android.

Comment: Not on the Google Play Store, for sure. Other app stores allow it.